# Navigation Controller not working when enabling ARC in xcode 5 and using ios 7

Tags: objective-c, ios7, xcode5

I enabled ARC and using ios 7 for my app.With out using xib i am doing programming.But i am unable to navigate from one view controller to another view controller.Created obj in .h file for a class.

In .h file 
 @property(nonatomic,strong)CountriesViewController *countryViewController;

In .m file in a button action.

```
countryViewController = [[CountriesViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:countryViewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: did you create navigationController in Appdelegate?

Comment: yes i created navigationController in AppDelegate

Comment: can you put your code?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add navigation Controller in AppDelegate like this,

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
     self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
// Override point for customization after application launch.
self.viewController = [[YourViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"YourViewController" bundle:nil];
self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

In your ViewController, navigate like this,

```
 self.countryViewController = [[CountriesViewController
 alloc]initWithNibName:@"CountriesViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.countryViewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: but i am not using story boards